# How to manage HikariCP connections when they leak?

Tags: java, servlets, database-connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp

We have a Java web application that gets a connection from Hikari connection pool (ver. 3.2.0) in an HttpServlet as soon as it receives a request and closes it when the response is returned.
We set the `leakDetectionThreshold` and the `connectionTimeout` so we can identify the connections that leaks.

In **"pseudocode"** it looks like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            String htmlResponse = doStuff(request, connection);
            response.write(htmlResponse);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            //handle exception
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    private String doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, Connection connection) {
        //...
    }

}
```

In `doStuff` we call an external service to get some data and sometimes it takes long to answer (>30 seconds), or we get no answer at all.

This (and the high traffic on the servlet) causes the pool to fill up and so we start getting the `Connection leak detection` warning and once there are no more idle connections the `SQLTransientConnectionException` is thrown with this message: `Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms`.

This is the behaviour expected form Hikari and is totally fine.

My quesiton is: how can we handle this situation? Are there other solutions than just intercept the leaked connections and close them?

Comment: This isn't a leak and I think you understand that. What is the application behavior that you are expecting when the service takes time?